# cmake Fetch Content Declare -- No such file or directory

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to fetch content Pistache repo from githubn Using the same concept with SQLiteC++ which one is working Pistache is throwing error message during the build.

Terminal after 'cmake --build .' :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lPistache: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/Chat_app.dir/build.make:147: src/Chat_app] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:257: src/CMakeFiles/Chat_app.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(Chat_app)

# SQLite requires at least C++11
# Pistache requires at least C++17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)
    message(STATUS "GCC detected, adding compile flags")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++98 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra")
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX)


include(FetchContent)
set(SQLITECPP_RUN_CPPLINT OFF CACHE INTERNAL "") 
FetchContent_Declare(
  SQLiteCpp
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp.git
  GIT_TAG        3.3.1
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(SQLiteCpp)
  
set(PISTACHE_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE INTERNAL "")
FetchContent_Declare(
  pistache
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/pistacheio/pistache.git
  GIT_TAG        0.0.5
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(pistache)

set(SOURCES "main.cpp" "generator.cpp" "user.cpp" "pugixml/src/pugixml.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})


target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  SQLiteCpp
  sqlite3
  pistache
  )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${SQLiteCpp_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${Pistache_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

Comment: The error message - `cannot find -lPistache` - does NOT correspond to your code. The error message is about `Pistache` (started with **uppercase** `P`), but in your code you have only `pistache` (lowercase).